# Nginx rewrite for a large group of URL's to a 444

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, rewrite

I am looking for a rewrite that will pick up any number of defined URL's and do a return 444 on any of them.  Rather than writing out each one individually, I was hoping for something where I could do like if location = *defined file or list* then return 444.

Example of what I am using for each URL, and this works.  I would just like to replace the wp-login.php to a list of some sort.

```
location = /wp-login.php {
    return 444;
}
```

EDIT:  I tried doing something like the below, but that did not work unfortunately

```
location = (/wp-login.php|/wp-admin.php) {
    return 444;
}
```

EDIT2:

Thanks Xavier Lucas, that is exactly what I needed.  I used what you mentioned and then added a bit to it to add more different formatted URLs.  We were getting a ton of spam to weird URL's so this worked nice.

```
    location ~ ^(/wp-(admin|login)\.php|/url/path(.*)|/url2(.*)) {
            return 444;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locations using regexs must use the operator `~` :

```
location ~ ^/wp-(admin|login)\.php$ {
    return 444;
}
```

Read [this part](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) of the official documentation to understand how locations work and [this other part](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) to understand what's the processing order.

Comment: Thanks so much Xavier, that is exactly what I needed!

EDIT:  Formatting in a reply is strange it seems.... ill edit my first comment.